# pktgen not sending packets more than 1kb big

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm using pktgen from this git repository https://github.com/danieltt/pktgen, and am sending packets from one ip address to another. This works except when spending packets in size greater than 1kb. Is this a known issue? Did anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Is your packet larger than the MTU of your interface?

Comment: Can you be more specific by stating the exact size of packet used .